Keras is being recognized but keras.models in not
This is. my code. In this code the keras.models is showing a problem and is saying that "Import "keras.models" could not be resolved", I tried to use
from keras.src.saving.saving_api import load_model

But then it stopped the problem but didnt complete the function. I would really appreciate if someone could help out thank you
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

st.title("Stock Price Predictor App")

stock = st.text_input("Enter the Stock ID", "GOOG")

end = pd.Timestamp.now()
start = end - pd.DateOffset(years=20)

google_data = yf.download(stock, start=start, end=end)

model = load_model("Latest_stock_price_model.keras")

st.subheader("Stock Data")
st.write(google_data)

splitting_len = int(len(google_data) * 0.7)
x_test = pd.DataFrame(google_data.Close[splitting_len:])

def plot_graph(figsize, values, full_data, extra_data=0, extra_dataset=None):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    plt.plot(values, 'Orange')
    plt.plot(full_data.Close, 'b')
    if extra_data and extra_dataset is not None:
        plt.plot(extra_dataset)
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.title('Stock Price and Moving Averages')
    plt.legend(['Moving Average', 'Close Price'])
    return fig

st.subheader('Original Close Price and MA for 250 days')
google_data['MA_for_250_days'] = google_data.Close.rolling(250).mean()
st.pyplot(plot_graph((15, 6), google_data['MA_for_250_days'], google_data, 0))

st.subheader('Original Close Price and MA for 200 days')
google_data['MA_for_200_days'] = google_data.Close.rolling(200).mean()
st.pyplot(plot_graph((15, 6), google_data['MA_for_200_days'], google_data, 0))

st.subheader('Original Close Price and MA for 100 days')
google_data['MA_for_100_days'] = google_data.Close.rolling(100).mean()
st.pyplot(plot_graph((15, 6), google_data['MA_for_100_days'], google_data, 0))

st.subheader('Original Close Price and MA for 100 days and MA for 250 days')
st.pyplot(plot_graph((15, 6), google_data['MA_for_100_days'], google_data, 1, google_data['MA_for_250_days']))

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(x_test[['Close']])

x_data = []
y_data = []

for i in range(100, len(scaled_data)):
    x_data.append(scaled_data[i-100:i])
    y_data.append(scaled_data[i])

x_data, y_data = np.array(x_data), np.array(y_data)

predictions = model.predict(x_data)

inv_pre = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)
inv_y_test = scaler.inverse_transform(y_data)

plotting_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'original_test_data': inv_y_test.reshape(-1),
    'predictions': inv_pre.reshape(-1)
}, index=google_data.index[splitting_len+100:])

st.subheader("Original values vs Predicted values")
st.write(plotting_data)

st.subheader('Original Close Price vs Predicted Close price')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6))
plt.plot(google_data.Close[:splitting_len+100], label='Original Close Price')
plt.plot(plotting_data['original_test_data'], label='Original Test data')
plt.plot(plotting_data['predictions'], label='Predicted Test data')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.title('Original Close Price vs Predicted Close Price')
st.pyplot(fig)

I am building a stock price prediction we app
